# Ansible compare zip listing to directory

Tags: ansible

EDIT: I resolved this a different way by getting a checksum of the 7z contents and checking

a) if the directory existed
b) if it did - did it's contents checksum match

---

I have an ansible playbook which uses a 7zip shell command, but I want to check if the 7z has been inflated already so I have the following

```
- name: Get zip listing
  shell: '7z l {{ sz_file }} | tail -n +21 | head -n -2 | cut -c 54-'
  register: sz_contents

- name: Compare zip listing to file contents
  stat:
    path: '{{ extract_dir }}/{{ item }}'
    register: result
  with_items: '{{ sz_contents.stdout_lines }}'

- name: Inflate 7z file if needed
  shell: 7z x {{ sz_file }}
  when: ???
```

I want the following to happen:

1. Stop the Compare task the first time results.stat.exists == False (the 7z has many files and continuing the comparison after that is pointless)
2. Register if the file needs inflating and do so as needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make the extract task conditional on
whether the compare tasks succeeds or fails, and you want the compare
task to fail as soon as it finds a file that doesn't exist.

We can get *most* of the way there.

Normally, the `stat` module doesn't trigger a failure when you point
it at a path that doesn't exist.  For example, the following playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - stat:
        path: /does-not-exist
      register: result

    - debug:
        var: result
```

Yields:

```
TASK [stat] ***********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "stat": {
            "exists": false
        }
    }
}
```

Ansible provides us with the `failed_when` directive to control when a
task fails.  This means we can rewrite your compare task to fail on a
missing file like this:

```
- name: Compare zip listing to file contents
  stat:
    path: '{{ extract_dir }}/{{ item }}'
  register: result
  failed_when: not result.stat.exists
  ignore_errors: true
  with_items: '{{ sz_contents.stdout_lines }}'
```

The `failed_when` directive tells Ansible to consider the task
"failed" if the file passed to `stat` doesn't exist, and the
`ignore_errors` directive tells Ansible to continue executing the
playbook rather than aborting when the task fails.

We can make the extract task condition on this one with a simple
`when` directive:

```
- name: Inflate 7z file if needed
  shell: 7z x {{ sz_file }}
  when: result is failed
```

The only problem with this solution is that Ansible won't exit a loop
when an individual item causes a failure, so it's going to check
through all of `sz_contents.stdout_lines` regardless.

**Update**

I was discussing this issue on irc and @bcoca pointed out the `when`
is evaluated before `register`, so we can actually get the behavior
you want by writing the compare task like this:

```
- name: Compare zip listing to file contents
  stat:
    path: '{{ extract_dir }}/{{ item }}'
  register: result
  when: result is defined or result is success
  failed_when: not result.stat.exists
  ignore_errors: true
  with_items: '{{ sz_contents.stdout_lines }}'
```

The `when` statement will cause all loop iterations after the first
failure to be skipped.